# put white spaces into numeric array perl

Tags: regex, perl

I have two string in file

```
87 33 21 34 51
```

and

```
35 27 10 70 61
```

I read them into array, then cut whitespaces by `tr/ //ds;`, then sort array.
How can I separate digit by whitespaces? Because now it contain 3527107061 and
8733213451. I need 35 27 10 70 61 and 87 33 21 34 51.

Example:

```
open(FD, "<", "$input_file") or die "Could not open file '$input_file' $!";
@file_content = <FD>;
close (FD); 

@sorted = sort { $a <=> $b } @file_content;
```

Comment: Why are you removing spaces?

Comment: Because if I sort array it show warnings -  argument isn't numeric in sort.

Comment: Please, show us the piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort without removing the spaces:

**Edit:** according to comments, here is a sort by only first digits.

```
use Data::Dumper;
use Modern::Perl;

my @arr = ('35 33 21 34 51', '4 27 10 70 61');
@arr = sort { $a =~ s/^(\d+).+/$1/gr <=> $b =~ s/(\d+).+/$1/gr } @arr;
say Dumper\@arr;
```

**Output:**

```
$VAR1 = [
          '4 10 70 61',
          '87 33 21 34 51'
        ];
```

Comment: Does that not sort alphabetically, rather than numerically?

Comment: @Sobrique: Yes, it does. But in this case (ie. only digits and spaces) it works.

Comment: No, I agree - it works for this use case. I would suggest it's worth noting the distinction though.

Comment: @Toto: if array will be contain line with first digit '4', sort doesn't work as expected, because it places line with 4 before line with 87.

Comment: @ViktorPredybaylo: Sorry, I don't get you, `4` is less than `87` isn't it? So it is before.

Comment: @Toto: Sorry my bad explain,  it places line with 4 before line with 87, but afte line with first digit 35.

Comment: @ViktorPredybaylo: Do you want to sort ONLY by first digits or by ALL digits contained in a line?

Comment: Toto: Only by first digits.

Comment: @ViktorPredybaylo: See my edit, is that what you want?

Answer (score 4):

You don't want - or need - to remove spaces, just parse them into an array.

```
my $str1 = '87 33 21 34 51';
my @array_of_numbers = split ' ', $str1; 

print join " ", sort @array_of_numbers;
```

If you're sorting without modification, it may be useful to know that `sort` allows you to take a custom sort argument. So this will do what you want:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

chomp ( my @arr = <DATA> );


print join "\n", sort { $a =~ s/\s+//gr <=> $b =~ s/\s+//gr } @arr;

__DATA__
87 33 21 34 51
35 27 10 70 61
```

Note - we use the `r` regex flag to return-but-not-modify, so it's *sorting* based on the (numeric values) of the numbers when compressed together - just like you're doing.

However, it'll behave a bit oddly if you're using something other than 2 digit numbers as a result.

Comment: @Sobrique toolic is write, I need to sort lines by first digit

Comment: First digit, or first _pair_ of digits? And what about the rest of the numbers in the list?

Comment: @Sobrique first pair of digits, but it can be one digit.